# Avoid callbackHell with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm starting with node mongoose etc... I'm a good student and so I follow the doc : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html .

After a while using this syntax I ended up with the infamous callback hell. After reading a lot about how to avoid this situation I decided to go for the promise way ^^. Also async module is really tempting but I don't know if it's suited for what I want to achieve.

I just want to save an object with all the corresponding refs.
According to the doc we have :

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

And for saving ref I use :

```
var aaron = new Person({ _id: 0, name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  var story1 = new Story({
    title: "Once upon a timex.",
    _creator: aaron._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });

  story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    aaron.stories.push(story1); // I added those two lines
    aaron.save(callback); // in order to save the refs to children
    // thats it!
  });
})
```

How can I achieve the same thing using promises the proper way ? or maybe Async is more suited ? I'm lost help ?

Comment: have you tried wait.for? https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH is super verbose not sure if there is a shorter way to deal with this

Try this? (may not be syntactically exact.. typed on fly)

```
var save = function(aaron){ 
   return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     aaron.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        reject(err); 
      }else{
        resolve(aaron);
      }
     });
   });
};

var addStory = function(aaron{
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     var story1 = new Story({
      title: "Once upon a timex.",
      _creator: aaron._id    // assign the _id from the person
     });
     story1.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }else{
        resolve(story1, arron);
      }
     });
  });
};

//then to exec the promises
save(arron).then(function(arron){
 addStory(arron);
}).then(function(story1, arron)){
  // tell the story?
}).catch(function(err){
    handleError(err);
});
```

**EDIT**

This should make it short

```
var saves = function(objToSave){
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    objToSave.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }else{
        resolve(objToSave);
      }
   })
  });
}

var _scope = this;
saves(arron).then(function(arron){
   var story1 = new Story({
     title: "Once upon a timex.",
     _creator: aaron._id    // assign the _id from the person
   });

  _scope.saves(story1)
}).then(function(story1){
  //do something with the story
}).catch(function(err){
  handleError(err);
});
```

Comment: What is TBH ? My aim here is to find the best way to achieve this saving thing ;). If you know any other way to do it I'll be glad to here about.

Comment: TBH is short hand for 'To Be Honest'. The code there will do the job using RSVP promise. You can maybe make the RSVP creation more generic for saves but the code should work.

Comment: :$ -feeling ashamed for the TBH- Yea true it's lot better than what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example of how you could do it with promises:

```
function save(obj) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        obj.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(obj);
            }
        });
    });
}

var aaron = new Person({ _id: 0, name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

save(aaron).then(function (savedAaron) {
    var story1 = new Story({
        title: 'Once upon a timex.',
        _creator: savedAaron._id
    });
    return save(story1);
}).then(function (savedStory) {
    aaron.stories.push(savedStory);
    return aaron.save(callback);
}).catch(function (err) {
    handleError(err);
});
```

I recommend reading this article on promises: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: well it's a nice one ! But I may go again in the callback hell with the then inside the then and so one. stupid question : new RSVP.Promise == new Promise ?

Comment: There exist multiple libs which have much in common but also differences in their APIs. I personally like the lib [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise). It's a polyfill of ES6 Promises and a subset of rsvp.js (see also http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-javascript-promises)

Comment: @Su4p A little late, but I've updated my answer: There is no then inside then anymore.